# kjscompiler gives errors on javascript built-in functions (google closure compiler)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

When compiling with kjscompiler (which uses google closure compiler), I get errors like this:

```
Error #3: variable Date is undeclared
Error #4: variable NaN is undeclared
Error #5: variable Error is undeclared
Error #6: variable Math is undeclared
```

Why is that? Do I need to add some sort of dependency?

https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are not including the default externs. In particular, the es3.js extern file (or equivalent) is required. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/477